# Global "using SpriteBatch = MySpriteBatch" for all file's, not per file

Tags: c#, xna, overriding, c-preprocessor, using-directives

In my XNA game, I have extended SpriteBatch to override some of the functions to do what I want, and added a few of my own.

I wanted force other members to use this class without having to change all instances of "SpriteBatch" to "MySpriteBatch"

In files, you can do something like:

```
using SpriteBatch = MySpriteBatch; // Overrides the Microsoft Spritebatch
```

However, this is for every file I must include this. It gets even more annoying if we did this for more than just SpriteBatch, or if we wanted to define some verbose type (Project.Class.ThisEnum)

Is there a way to define these names globally, once, for the whole project?

I've seen something like this before in a C++ project where they had a Precompiled header included to every file, and inside was all the renames, such as:

```
#define INT int //INT is now the same as int
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# - ". That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "global" way to do this in C#.

That being said, depending on what you're doing, you may be able to accomplish your goals by using [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).  This can provide the illusion of "adding methods" to the type without actually creating your own type.

Comment: Too bad about being no global. However, the extention methods should work for me, thank you for the tip!